# How to specify the orientation of an area vector?

Tags: vectors, conventions, geometry

We all know that the area of a triangle having consecutive sides as $\vec { a }$ and $\vec { b }$ is $\frac { 1 } { 2 } | \vec { a } \times \vec { b } |$, but what is the direction of that area vector? I mean if we consider $\vec { a } \times \vec { b } $ that will be one direction and if we consider $\vec { b } \times \vec { a }$ then that will be the opposite direction but we know that a vector always has a particular direction so how do we specify the orientation of the area vector in this case?

Comment: You choose, as a matter of convention.

Comment: The cross product assigns a direction (by convention) to the normal vector, with a magnitude "equal" to the area. I air quoted "equal" b/c there is a dimension problem in your vector space. All these issue are resolved in Geometric Algebra. The cross product is replaced by the exterior product, and that really is an oriented _surface_.

Comment: Sorry, but I really couldn't understand your explanation, can you please explain in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit research I got my answer  that is whether you consider $ \vec{a} \times \vec{b}$ or the reverse ,the direction is same because the angle should always be in counter clockwise direction.

Answer (score 0):

A triangle defined by three position vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ has

- Direction vector along

  $$ \vec{n} =  (\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) + (\vec{b} \times \vec{c}) + (\vec{c} \times \vec{a}) $$
- The area of the triangle is $$A = \frac{1}{2} \| \vec{n} \| $$
- The centroid is at $$ \vec{g} = \frac{1}{3} \left( \vec{a}+  \vec{b} + \vec{c} \right) $$

The convention is that when the vertices are taken in sequence (*ABC* for example below), the direction is defined along your thumb as seen below using the *right hand rule*.

[image: pic]

Comment: The vertices are in 3D space. If you look at them from the other side, “clockwise” is ACB.

Comment: Point taken. I meant to say that the direction depends on the sequence you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Area doesn’t really have a direction. Sometimes area vectors rather than area scalars are used, but their direction is arbitrary and meaningless. The common convention for a differential area element $d\vec{a}$ on a closed surface (like a sphere or torus) is to choose it to point outward.

The lesson here is that vector algebra is sometimes useful even when you aren’t calculating a vector quantity!

Comment: while the area direction may be meaningless and/or arbitrary the direction of circulation along its perimeter is important and is not arbitrary.

Comment: @hyportnex No. The “direction of circulation” in ja72’s triangle is either ABC or ACB, and deciding between these is arbitrary and meaningless.

Comment: A *real* current has actual charges moving, the actual direction of this actual motion is not arbitrary, it curls either this way or that way and it an actual curling. Whether we assign a positive or a negative signs to that actual curling motion is arbitrary, and that is all I am saying.  But it is possible to ignore (and overcome) this arbitrariness by treating the magnetic field, torque or area-form not as a vector but as an anti-symmetric (skew-symmetric) 3D tensor (dyad, 2-form) in which case you do not have to deal with the "swimming rules" (right/left hand-screw rule, etc.)